# Setting checked property of input with jQuery.prop & object literal - two different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I had this piece of code that created selected checkbox:

```
$("<input />", { type: 'checkbox', checked: true});
```

And later I appended it to the form...

This code works in IE8 and below. However I've encountered an issue in IE9 (it could also be the case in other browsers, but I haven't investigated it). Checkbox was created but it was not checked (when looking at markup it had no checked attribute).

However when I've changed it to:

```
$("<input />", { type: 'checkbox' }).prop('checked', true);
```

checked control works in every browser.

Why first method was failing?

Comment: aren't you missing the `type: checkbox` property

Comment: my bad - I forgot to include type: checkbox in code snippet, but I have it in my oryginal code

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Btw, `.prop('checked', true)` will not create a `checked` *attribute* in any browser (in the markup), it will just check the checkbox.

Comment: a) Version of jQuery is 1.10.2. b) anyway, checkbox was not checked

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the input type also

```
$("<input />", { checked: true, type: 'checkbox'}).appendTo('body');
```